# Logitech Ultrathin mouse scroll behaviour on mac

Tags: mac, mouse, macos

i am using a Logitech UltraThin T630 mouse with a macbook pro (2015, os 10.11.1) and i am having a strange scroll behaviour. I mean its working but its different to the mouse working on windows.

Let try to describe it:

Normally (and on windows) scrolling works directly. When i scroll on the mouse, the site (i.e. in a webbrowser) moves directly. But on mac this mouse starts scrolling as soon as i release the finger from the mouse. This leads to an indirect scrolling which is annoying.

Does anybody has the same issue and can deliver any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the case that anybody has the same problem:

Simply download 5.30.150 and use it. It works like a charm
http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/T651-Trackpad-and-Ultra-Thin-Touch-Mouse-issues-with-Logitech/m-p/1458806